# Меня уверяют в том что под Ubuntu есть уневерсальный драйвер NVidia, так ли это?

Tags: ubuntu, видеодрайвера

То есть я устанавливаю этот драйвер, запускаю на железе с разными видеокартами, и у меня сразу всё работает.

Правда ли это?

Comment: Неправда. В открытом драйвере работает не всё, в разные версии проприетарного драйвера поддерживают разные модели видеокарт

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый отклик! То есть если меня просят собрать дистрибутивы linux c проприетарным драйвером, то нужно уточнить какие модели видекарт нужно поддерживать?

Comment: Наверное. Стоит отметить, что та же убунта вроде как сама умеет выбирать подходящую версию драйвера (в её репозиториях есть куча версий для разных видеокарт)

Comment: Ага понял, благодарю.

Comment: А с AMD тоже самое?

Comment: Мне по жизни не доводилось работать с AMD, так что не в курсе. Но скорее всего по сути будет примерно то же самое, ведь производителям вряд ли интересно поддерживать доисторические модели видеокарт

Comment: Ну да логично...